# Unable to find version '0.4.0.203' of package 'SolrNet'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am rebuilding C# project and getting below error.
Unable to find version '0.4.0.203' of package 'SolrNet'

[I try to install that version through here but not able to find that speicfic version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPfUP.png)

I need help how I can required SolrNet versions through "Manage NuGet packages"

Comment: I don't see that version of that package on the public feed https://www.nuget.org/packages/SolrNet#versions-body-tab, maybe change your application to use a different version? Based on similar versions, that version came out in 2015, nearly a decade ago.

Comment: NuGet will cache packages. Is it possible that there might be a copy of the package (downloaded long ago) in another project, user account, or machine? As @gunr2171 said, the package version is not available in NuGet.